# When you download an Xbox One game from the store, is it available to all users of that Xbox?

Tags: xbox-one

If I buy a game on the Xbox One from the store, will it be available to all users on that Xbox? Is it the same as if I purchased a disc, where it is available to any user?

Comment: So if I buy a game, download it and purchase it on Xbox A, will it not be registered to that console? If I download it to Xbox B, I should be able to play it as Live will recognise my ownership. But Xbox A should have it registered for offline use in theory. Must test this. Anyone?

Comment: I know it is a question though the answer will elaborate on this question more thouroughly.

Answer (score 8):

The best answer I can find is this quote from the Microsoft Xbox One Support Site:

> **Q: Can multiple people share the same console?**
>
> A: An unlimited number of people can share the same console.
>
> Note: Your friends and family will only be able to play your games if the sharing feature is enabled.

Source: http://support.xbox.com/en-NZ/xbox-one/games/my-home-xbox

There is also [this page](http://support.xbox.com/en-NZ/xbox-one/games/playing-across-multiple-consoles) regarding playing your Digital Purchases on OTHER Xbox One consoles.

Note: The link to "About sharing games & Gold" is a dead link, but I believe it was meant to point to my previous link.

Answer (score 7):

A digital download can be used by any/all users of the purchasers "home" Xbox One console. It can also be downloaded and played on any other console but only as long as the purchaser is signed into that other console.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set a family in the xbox.

In the Xbox settings you can find 'Family'. That's where you can set that all your users are in family.